# PDO checking if user has enter all fields

Tags: php

I can't seem to send a error message to my users who leave a blank field. How can I go about this? EX: if they forget to enter a password: echo FORGOT PASSWORD and etc.

```
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        require 'core/connect.php';

            $query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)");

                $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
                $query->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password']);

                if($query->execute()){
                    header("Location: index.php");
                } else{
                    echo 'ERROR';
                }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why do you expect an error? If they leave the field blank, it will just insert blank values into the table.

Comment: How can I stop them from leaving a blank field. sorry.

Comment: What is the full error message you get?

Comment: if you want user to enter form fields then you need to do validations at server side and if your interested you can do at client side also. This you need to learn, its possible to write whole validation code here.

Comment: PDO has nothing to do with HTML form fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the fields are blank, use `empty()`:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        echo "Username and password must be filled in";
    } else {
        // Code to insert into database and redirect
    }
}
```